# Is there any way to change props value of a Vue Component from method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-datepicker

I'm using two "vuejs-datepicker" components in my Vue when i click on of the datepicker which is been named as a "activityFrom" and select the date upon the closing the datepicker I'm triggering the component defined function "@selected" where am I need to the change the props of second datepicker "activityTo" which is disabledDates props.

This is my first component

```
<datepicker  @selected="changeNextDate" v-model="$v.fields.activityFrom.$model" :disabledDates="disabledDates" ></datepicker>
```

And this is my second component

```
<datepicker ref="activityTo" v-model="$v.fields.activityTo.$model" :disabledDates="disabledDates" ></datepicker>
```

This is my code

```
<script>
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';     
import moment from 'moment'; 
export default {
    name:'Home',
    data(){
        return{
            fields:{
                destination:'',
                activityFrom:'',
                activityTo:'',
            },
            disabledDates:{
                to: new Date((new Date().getTime()+(2*24*60*60*1000)) -  8640000)
            },
            disabledDates2:{
              to: new Date((new Date().getTime()+(3*24*60*60*1000)) -  8640000)
            }

        }
    },
    components:{
        Datepicker
    },
    methods:{
       customFormatter(date) {
          return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
       },
        changeNextDate(event){
            console.log('Date has been seleced');
            this.$refs.activityTo.disabledDates = disabledDates2;
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

But when i tried to change the props from method it is sending me the following error

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
> whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
> computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
> "disabledDates"

Is there any solution for changing the props becasue i really do change the second element upon clicking on the function of first element. Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to access `this.$refs.activityTo` in order to update the props for your second component. Since the props are being passed down from your parent you can just update them there, e.g.:

```
changeNextDate(event){
  this.disabledDates = this.disabledDates2;
}
```

Also I'm not sure why you're using that `v-model` syntax; I've never seen that before and I don't think it should be necessary. You can just do it like this: `v-model="fields.activityFrom"` and `v-model="fields.activityTo"`.

Comment: This will also apply to the actrivityFrom "disabledDate" maybe I can  change the prop of disabledDates to disabledDates2 in activityTo

Comment: Yeah if the `disabledDate` value should be different in your datepicker components then you will need to create two separate properties in the parent and pass down the correct one.